# The render is different from the camera view

Tags: rendering

I am doing the Blender Guru doughnut, the view is like that on the left, but the render on the right is different from it, as if the weight painting has not been applied at all. What could have gone wrong?

[image: Viewport on the left, render result on the right]
[image: user interface]

[image: Particle properties]

[image: Some more particle properties]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/7kjnP3AO/

Comment: mmmh actually I see the same as your image on the right, in both render and 3D view...

Comment: It is the vertex groups - density setting. But even after toggling it, the render is still different. And every time I close the file and re-open it, the setting is back to not-toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you've created a keyframe on the particle's *Vertex Group Density*, so even if you toggle it, it doesn't take it into account, you need to select the object, open the *Timeline* and delete the keyframe.

Comment: It is solved! Thank you!

Comment: Please consider to accept the answer @Franc How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour